# Acumatica Mobile Modify the Location fields to be able to scan a barcode

Tags: acumatica

We are currently using the Acumatica Mobile to process Bin Transfers. We are also looking at the Scandit app to be able to scan the from and to bin location labels in the warehouse. So far with testing We can scan the locations, but only in the search window. We would like to be able to scan/enter the locations on the main screen without going to the search window. It seems the selector forces you to go to the search window. Is there a way around this in Acumatica Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly old question with a relatively new solution.  I am using 2020R1 where we now can leverage the built-in scanning capability in the Mobile App.

Your field must be defined in the ASPX as a textedit.  Then simply add the field to the mobile app screen (if not already there) and decorate it with **special = BarCodeScan** as shown in the example below.

```
add screen ZZ301000 {
add container "ScanContainer" {
    add field "MyBarcode"
    {
      special = BarCodeScan
    }
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add recordAction "Save" {
      behavior = Save
    }
    add recordAction "Cancel" {
      behavior = Cancel
    }
    add recordAction "Insert" {
      behavior = Create
    }
  }
}
```

The result will be similar to the image below:
[image: Barcode Scanner on Description Field]

By clicking on the barcode icon, the built-in barcode reader will open to utilize the camera to scan the barcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set **ForceType** to *"String"* for the Location field to replace selector with a text edit. This will allow to type values directly on the form, but you will loose all selector functionality, like searching for records. Another option is to set the **PickerType** property to *Searchable*. For more information about the Field tag attributes, please refer to [Acumatica Product Documentation](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1bfb3bcd-9def-44e7-a7b0-6c524e951c09)

Comment: When scanning a Bar Code in Acumatica, you can see the field populate into the screen. However, when you scan the same bar code in Acumatica Mobile, it will not display on the screen. I have tried it on several fields on the screen from note fields, to just straight text fields, but in Acumatica Mobile, it does not seen to accept a scan of a bar code from a wedge. DO we need to code it differently to handle this. Or is this something tat can not be done in the Acumatica Mobile product.

Comment: If none of the options suggested above made the mobile app respect scanned barcodes, I'm afraid, currently there is no other option to achieve the desired behavior. I also found one similar idea (https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-1320) on the Ideas for Acumatica website - your vote will help to get more attention from the PM Team and hopefully include this feature in the roadmap for future releases.